# Copy paste with mupdf in MacOS

Tags: terminal, keyboard, pdf, copy-paste

I would like to copy paste with mupdf in MacOS. I can successfully highlight text by using the CTRL button and the mouse button. But I cannot copy the highlighted text.

I tried the following in (found on this archlinux thread: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=263759).

"
Try something like this:

1. First way: double click or select some text in mupdf (don't mind if selection disappears) and then open your favorite text terminal and press shift+insert or ctrl+shift+v,
2. Second way: select some text in mupdf and while holding LMB press ctrl+c  (don't mind if selection disappears) and then open your favorite text terminal and press shift+insert or ctrl+shift+v.
   "

But it didn't work
Does somebody knows how to do it?

Comment: You could try SHIFT CTRL C to copy in mupdf, and then Command V to Paste in another app; but I doubt that mupdf supports the MacOS pasteboard. You may have to use a 'proper' Mac app. Or Preview.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @benwiggy. I just tried it, unfortunately it doesn't work... :(

Comment: I was able to copy a TIFF image of the current page to the clipboard using Command C, but I've not managed to make a selection of text: the highlighting doesn't hold when I release the mouse.